# rails 5 form_with not processing nor permitting nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A parent class 'model'

```
has_many :modelbodycontacts
has_many :bodycontacts, through: :modelbodycontacts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :modelbodycontacts, allow_destroy: true
```

modelbodycontacts being a join table for model and bodycontact.
The related controller permits

```
params.require(:model).permit(:name, :modelbodycontact_attributes)
```

However, using `form_with`

```
<%= form_with(model: model, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields(:modelbodycontact) do |bodycontact_fields| %>
    <% @bodycontacts.each do |bodycontact| %>  
      <%= bodycontact_fields.check_box :bodycontact_id %><%= bodycontact.name %>
    <% end %>  
  <% end %>
```

generates the following HTML

```
<input name="model[modelbodycontact][bodycontact_id]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="model[modelbodycontact][bodycontact_id]" id="model_modelbodycontact_bodycontact_id" />  Seat
<input name="model[modelbodycontact][bodycontact_id]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="model[modelbodycontact][bodycontact_id]" id="model_modelbodycontact_bodycontact_id" />  Back
```

submitting data leads to `Unpermitted parameter: :modelbodycontact`

There are a few errors here:

- the bodycontact_id is not being generated in the HTML code, only the checked/unchecked values, thus a child record cannot be properly created
- the parameters are not being permitted; particularly, the reference is to the model name, not its attribute(s)
- [Documentation indicates](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with) that "The form_with method automatically includes the model id as a hidden field in the form."  Well, it ain't there... But possibly Rails handles that internally knowing it is a nested

One could revert to `form_for` and its tried and tested ways, but that will be eventuall be deprecated.  How can `form_with` be properly used here?

Answer (score 0):

changing param option in controller

```
    params.require(:model).permit(:name, modelbodycontact_attributes: [])
```

and

```
    <%= form.fields("modelbodycontact_attributes[]") do |bodycontact_fields| %>
        <% @bodycontacts.each do |bodycontact| %>  
          <%= bodycontact_fields.check_box :bodycontact_id %><%= bodycontact.name %>
        <% end %>  
    <% end %>
```

should work i think